# Remove entity from joint table without affecting parent - EF Core 2.2

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have an issue with many-to-many relationship, and I do not understand why it is behaving this way:

so I have the following:

```
public class A 
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<AB> ABs { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class B 
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<AB> ABs { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class AB 
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public A A { get; set; }
    public Guid A_Id { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
    public Guid B_Id { get; set; }

    internal static void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<AB>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.A_Id, e.B_Id}).IsUnique();

            entity.HasOne(e => e.A)
                .WithMany(p => p.ABs)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.A_Id)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
                
            entity.HasOne(e => e.B)
                .WithMany(w => w.ABs)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.B_Id)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            });
        }
}
```

I am keep getting:

> The association between entity types 'A' and 'AB' has been severed but
> the relationship is either marked as 'Required' or is implicitly
> required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the
> dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship
> is severed, then setup the relationship to use cascade deletes.
> Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to
> see the key values.

Issue is that I want to break the relationship, by deleting AB from A.ABs, and EF Core tries to delete A. I do not understand what's going on. Any ideas?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Why did you put on modelcreating inside of AB class? It should be inside of dbcontext.

And try add a key to you AB class too. Since you are using v.2.2 it will make EF more relaible.

```
public class A 
{
    public Guid Id{ get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<AB> ABs { get; set; }
}
public class B 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<AB> ABs { get; set; }
}
public class AB 
{   
    public Guid Id { get; set; }    
    public A A { get; set; }
    public Guid A_Id { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
    public Guid B_Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: on model creating is in this place because my team has chosen to do it this way, i have no other choice.

Comment: also, i do have guid on AB class, i forgot to add it